# Add existing gitlab project to a group/subgroup

Tags: gitlab

I have a gitlab group with some subgroups within in it. I would like to transfer repositories that were created independently to a subgroup of mine. Is there a way to do this, with all the members, history, commits, etc that are currently in the projects. I can simply create a new project in the subgroup and transfer the files there, but we will lose the history, etc.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 1):

In your project, go to Settings -> General,
then expand "Advanced" and go to the "Transfer project" section (in red),
in the "select a new namespace" list, select your groupe.